Is there a way to know which .user.ini files have been loaded for the currently running php script?
Since the .user.ini per directory php ini files can be used to set the auto_append_file setting, thus prepending each and every php script in the folder with another script, I wanted to know if and how can a script check which .user.ini files have been loaded in the currently running environment.
I've checked the phpinfo(); output, and that ONLY lists the php.ini file/files loaded, NOT the .user.ini files (it only lists the settings regarding the .user.ini, such as name and ttl).
I've also checked the php_ini_scanned_files() function output, but still no luck: this too only returns php.ini files and IGNORES .user.ini.
I'm starting to think that the only way is to simply check if the currently running script folder (and all its parent folders up to the document root) contain an .user.ini file, and  if found then assume that it has been loaded and applied...
Am I right or am I missing something simple and should bang my head on the wall? :)
Thanks for any hint!

"These files are processed only by the CGI/FastCGI SAPI." Are you using CGI?

Yes, but in any case .user.ini files ARE working properly, and my question was NOT about making them work, but about how to sense which .user.ini files were loaded.
